# Is there a word for being untruthful because you think you are right but you aren't?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the following action:

Presume that we have a person who has never eaten parsley.  He is speaking with another person who also has never eaten parsley.  He tells that person that he doesn't like parsley because it's too spicy.  He believes that it's true because someone *else* told him, so he's avoided parsley his whole life.

He's not lying, because that would imply he knows the truth but is intentionally saying otherwise.  However, he's not being truthful either.  Is there a word for this?

Comment: Misinformed?  Willfully ignorant?

Comment: @StevenLittman Would it be *willfully* ignorant? It seems more the individual doesn't know any better. I would feel they are being *unintentionally* ignorant.

Comment: I'd think it's a question of submitting to the claims of someone else without finding out for himself.  That would be willfully ignorant; he couldn't bother to find out the truth.  We're suffering from a lot of that in the US these days, over matters far more important than what parsley tastes like.

Comment: Misinformed sounds about right, actually

Comment: Misinformed is to receive incorrect information. But _misguided_ is to have one's behaviour adversely affected by the untruthfulness of another.

Comment: @NigelJ I think misinformed is best. Misguided works better when the person is adversely affected in a significant way. It's not exactly a big deal that this person doesn't eat parsley. But if he spent all his money on lottery tickets thinking that the odds were in his favor, then he truly is misguided.

Comment: @ktm5124 I'm sticking with _misguided_. Today it's don't eat parsley, tomorrow it's don't take your medicine.

Comment: _Mistaken_ also works.

Comment: @NigelJ Hehe, good point.

Comment: @Xanne, for the win!